# How to update original estimate using Groovy in Jira without changes in history?

Tags: groovy, jira

I want to update Original Estimate field using Groovy in Scriptrunner that way changes will not appear in history.

I know that customfield.updatevalue() method does what i want, but it's for custom fields, not for TimeTracking field.

In documentation I saw a matching method

```
updateValue(FieldLayoutItem fieldLayoutItem, Issue issue, ModifiedValue modifiedValue, IssueChangeHolder issueChangeHolder)
```

, but there is 2 problems:

1. I dont know how to retrieve this field for an issue
2. And what modifiedValue should look like in code